# How to convert pick-up and drop-off coordinates into rows & columns in a 2D character array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

Previously I have asked a question on how to open a character text file into a 2D character array. It's a map that a robot is assigned to pick-up packages & drop them off at another coordinate with roads, buildings & a central road which consume more time to move. I'm able to read a map[15][15] & store into 2D char array. But now, let's say my robot starting point is at no.48, how do I convert that number into the 4th row, 3rd column of the 2D char array map? How do I continue frm this step? The no. might b random but I juz wanna know how to let the char array know which row & column is that no. in.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream in;
char s;
char map[15][15];
int i,j, r = 0, c = 0;

in.open("city.txt");
if(!in.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File open error! " << endl;
    }
else
    {
        while(!in.eof())
        {
            in >> s;
            if(in.eof()) break;
            map[r][c] = s;
            c++;
            if(c > 14)
            {
                r++;
                c = 0;
            }
        }
        in.close();

        for(i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 15; j++)
                cout << map[i][j];
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int row =pos/15;
int column=pos%15
```

where `pos` is the position of the bot

Answer (score 0):

Lets take an grid of NxN where N=4. Your numbers are laid out as following:

```
00, 01, 02, 03,
04, 05, 06, 07,
08, 09, 10, 11,
12, 13, 14, 15,
```

You can use integer division (/) to retrieve the row:

```
2/N  = row 0
10/N = row 2
15/N = row 3
```

And you can use modulo (%) to retrieve the column:

```
2%N  = column 2
10%N = column 2
15%N = column 3
```

In your case you use N=15

Comment: Brilliant! But do I need to +1 into the rows because usually we humans start frm row 1 (1st row).. Or do I leave it be because it's how C++ language should display?

Comment: When you are communicating with a user, you can add output+1 or input-1 for readability. Within the application leave it as is

Comment: Oh u mean at the cout << r+1 ?
Btw, as I'm reading the txt file named "Packages.txt" that contains the pickup & dropoff coordinates, It was given as 46, 50
111, 50
16, 85
I notice the comma produce problems cuz it reads 1 value, space, den another value.. How do I fix this without having to remove the comma as this coordinates might be entered by a user?